# How to break down terraform state file

Tags: module, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am looking for guidance/advice on how to best break down a terraform state file into smaller state files.

We currently have one state file for each environment and it has become unmanageable so we are now looking to have a state file per terraform module so we need to separate out the current state file.

Would it be best to point it to a new s3 bucket, then run a plan and apply for the broken down modules and generate a fresh state file for each module or is there an easier or better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

This all depends upon how your environment has been provisioned and how critical the down time is ?

Below are the two general scenarios, I can think of from your question.

First Scenario - ( if you can take down time )

1. Destroy everything that you got and start from scratch by defining separate backend for each module and provision the infrastructure from that point on. So now you can have backend segregation and infrastructure management becomes easier.

Second Scenario - ( If you can't take down time )

1. Lets' say you are running mission critical workloads that absolutely can't take any down time.
2. In this case, you will have to come up with proper plan of migrating huge monolith backend to smaller backends.
3. Terraform has the command called `terraform state mv` which can help you with migrating one terraform state to another one.
4. When you work on the scenario, start from lower level environments and work from there.
5. Note down any caveats that you are encountering during these migration in lower level environments, the same caveats will apply in higher level environments as well

Some useful links
https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/state/mv.html
https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/init.html#backend-initialization

Answer (score 0):

Although the only other answer (as of now) lists only two options - the other option is that you can simply make terraform repos (or folders, however you are handling your infrastructure) - and then do `terraform import` to bring existing infrastructure into those (hopefully) repos.

Once all of the imports have proven to be successful, you can remove the original repo/source/etc. of the monolithic terraform state.

The caveat is that the code for each of the new state sources must match the existing code and state, otherwise this will fail.